# 'charmap' codec error when trying to extract the html page using Beautiful Soup - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I try to load any page using the code below  it is grabbing just the tag <"head"> and not the entire html  etc.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.tushmedia.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml-xml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

But if I remove the 'xml' and just leave `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')` it will generate an error:

'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 11051: character maps to

It is because when I removed the "xml" part it will not grab the xml and will not generate an output and when it tries to grab the HTML it generate this error. I think it is regarding with a UTF-8 encode issue, but any idea how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to encode it to `utf-8`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.tushmedia.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: actually, as the error shows `can't encode character u'\u2019'`,suspect the default encoding is not 'utf-8', then comes out the idea.

Comment: And do you have any idea how to ignore this error, or avoid my program to stop because of it?

Comment: do you try my answer?

Comment: yeah and it worked, but is that ok to use a hardcode like that to fix this issue?

Comment: the thing is that it is related to your default encoding of `print`, it will try to encode all unicode content to your encoding type, during this convert, your encoding raised the error. you can use `utf-8` which is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible characters defined by Unicode. If my answer is solution, pls mark it as correct answer even it is down vote.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, yeah your answer was my solution, I will need to add this ".encode('utf-8')) for every print with text, but at least it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is something contra-intuitive but

- `"lxml"`        is a `HTML` parser, while
- `"lxml-xml"` is an `XML` parser

`u'\u2019'` is the right quote character (fancy, curly) which has no representation in ASCII table.

BeautifulSoup uses a sub-library called `Unicode, Dammit` to detect a document’s encoding and convert it to `Unicode`. The auto-detected encoding is available as the `.original_encoding` attribute of the `BeautifulSoup` object.

`UnicodeDammit` guesses correctly most of the time, but sometimes it makes mistakes. Sometimes it guesses correctly, but only after a byte-by-byte search of the document that takes a very long time.

So you may add `from_encoding=` argument to your constructor:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, and you have any idea how can I avoid this issue, because it stops the program.

Comment: I expanded my answer, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sure I upvote your question. I think there is a small mistake in your example, the code would be?
`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: You are right, missing apostrophe... I am going to fix it in my answer. Thanks for your upvoting.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to grab the entire html you need to use `html.parser`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.tushmedia.com/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify)
```

I ran your code with `lxml-xml` and `xml` it worked nut returned only the
head as you said. There were no errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried to use "html.parser" previously but it wasn't working, I think I was probablying write something wrong. But when I use the BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lmxl-xml') the content come with a perfect structure, there is no way to do the same with the rest of the tags? without using the html.parse?

Comment: Like for example if I do the code below but for this specific site:

https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/

Then I'm printing exactly what I want all the html in a good structure:

`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())`